# Python web-scraping countdown timer values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape data from the following `<countdown>` element, specifically I am trying to get the values from `formatted_date`. I am not getting any luck and it is just printing `None`.

```
<countdown current_time="1611585537797" date="1611603000" listing="f446d440-9d45-4e48-bf93-69c5e117fac2" formatted_date="25th January 2021 19:30:00"></countdown>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question with the full code that you have already tried

Comment: Waiting for your update with the code you tried, I can already sense that you are trying to get a value from a tag that is being computed by Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

try this: We can access a tag’s attributes by treating it like a dictionary.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<countdown current_time="1611585537797" date="1611603000" listing="f446d440-9d45-4e48-bf93-69c5e117fac2" formatted_date="25th January 2021 19:30:00"></countdown>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

tag = soup.countdown
print(tag.attrs['formatted_date'])
```